# grails run-war causing SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: grails, slf4j, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, slf4j-api

I am using grails 2.4.2 version. When I run the command run-app then application runs fine, no error in Intellij console. When I run the command prod run-app, it also works fine without error. But when I run the command run-war then the following error is given. I have searched for it but no solutions is working for my case or I may not understanding.

Here my error below in Intellij console:

```
    |Done creating WAR target\alhikmah-0.1.war
|Running Grails application
Error |
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
Error |
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/aina/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-plugin-log4j/2.4.2/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error |
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/projects/alhikmah/target/work/tomcat/webapps/alhikmah/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error |
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Error |
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
Error |
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener).
Error |
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Error |
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(FeatureDescriptor.java:387)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.setMethod(MethodDescriptor.java:114)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:72)
    at java.beans.MethodDescriptor.<init>(MethodDescriptor.java:56)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1131)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:414)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161)
    ... 5 more
Error listenerStart
Context [/alhikmah] startup failed due to previous errors
The web application [/alhikmah] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
The web application [/alhikmah] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
The web application [/alhikmah] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/alhikmah
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/alhikmah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading your Grails version might solve your problem.
Procedure to upgrade

1. Project -> Clean
2. application.properties -> Change app.grails.version = (New version)
3. Your project -> Properties -> Grails -> Change grails installation to new grails version.
4. Your project -> Grails tools -> Refresh Dependencies
5. Run your project

Or have a look on it [Grails Upgrade](https://docs.grails.org/2.5.0/guide/upgradingFrom23.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in buildConfig.groovy

```
inherits("global") {
        excludes 'grails-plugin-log4j'
    }
```